# Why does function composition compose from right to left in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, composition, associative, function-composition

Function composition composes from right to left:

```
const comp  = f => g => x => f(g(x));
const inc = x => x + 1;
const dec = x => x - 1;
const sqr = x => x * x;
let seq = comp(dec)(comp(sqr)(inc));

seq(2); // 8
```

`seq(2)` is transformed to `dec(sqr(inc(2)))` and the application order is `inc(2)...sqr...dec`. Thus the functions are invoked in the reverse order in which they are passed to `comp`. This isn't intuitive for Javascript programmers, since they're used to method chaining, which goes from left to right:

```
o = {
  x: 2,
  inc() { return this.x + 1, this },
  dec() { return this.x - 1, this },
  sqr() { return this.x * this.x, this }
}

o.dec().sqr().inc(); // 2
```

I consider that confusing. Here's a reversed composition:

```
const flipped = f => g => x => g(f(x));
let seql = flipped(dec)(flipped(sqr)(inc));

seql(2); // 2
```

Are there any reasons why function composition goes from right to left?

Comment: "*Thus the functions are evaluated in the reverse order of their application*" - huh, what?

Comment: You seem to be asking why arguments (right) are evaluated before the function call (left), no?

Comment: Would it make more sense to you if `seq` was written `comp(comp(dec)(sqr))(inc)`? (function composition is commutative)

Comment: @Bergi I rephrased the sentence in question

Comment: @Bergi hm, that wouldn't change the fact, that comp is evaluated from right to left. I haven't any problems with it, I just ask why?

Comment: I basically boils down to "function evaluation is always right-to-left". It becomes more obvious if you treat composition as an infix operator.

Comment: @Bergi, well that sounds like a dogma. And we can't define our own infix operators in Javascript anyway.

Comment: Yes, you can call it dogma, I'd call it convention (stemming from maths): the arguments are always on the right of the function name. You can invert that (like `($ 5) inc` == `inc 5` in Haskell), but that is really just weird and confusing.

Comment: @Bergi I'm really bad at math, but isn't mathematical function composition associative that is, `f . (g . h) === (f . g) . h`? Anyway, if it has always been like that and many people are accustomed to it, I don't want to question it.

Comment: Oh, yeah I meant associativity of course. You confused me totally by saying that your `compl` function is "left-associative" while you actually commuted (swapped) the arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is actually about the order of arguments in a definition of the function composition operator rather than right- or left-associativity.  In mathematics, we usually write "f o g" (equivalent to comp(f)(g) in your definition) to mean the function that takes x and returns f(g(x)).  Thus "f o (g o h)" and "(f o g) o h" are equivalent and both mean the function that maps each argument x to f(g(h(x))).

That said, we sometimes write f;g (equivalent to compl(f)(g) in your code) to mean the function which maps x to g(f(x)).  Thus, both (f;g);h and f;(g;h) mean the function mapping x to h(g(f(x))).

A reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition#Alternative_notations

Comment: OK, I confused the commutative with the associative law. Thanks!

Comment: As to alternative notations (";"): we also find "pipe" operators like `>>>` or `|>`, which visualize the "left to right" concept better, IMO.

Answer (score 9):

To answer the original question: Why does function composition compose from right to left?

1. So it is traditionally made in mathematics
2. `comp(f)(g)(x)` has the same order as `f(g(x))`
3. It is trivial to create a reversed or forward composition (see example)

Forward function composition:

```
const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x));
const flip = f => x => y => f(y)(x);
const flipped = flip(comp);

const inc = a => a + 1;
const sqr = b => b * b;

   comp(sqr)(inc)(2); // 9, since 2 is first put into inc then sqr
flipped(sqr)(inc)(2); // 5, since 2 is first put into sqr then inc
```

This way of calling functions is called *currying*, and works like this:

```
// the original:
comp(sqr)(inc)(2); // 9

// is interpreted by JS as:
( ( ( comp(sqr) ) (inc) ) (2) ); // 9 still (yes, this actually executes!)

// it is even clearer when we separate it into discrete steps:
const compSqr = comp(sqr); // g => x => sqr(g(x))
compSqr(inc)(2);   // 9 still
const compSqrInc = compSqr(inc); // x => sqr(x + 1)
compSqrInc(2);     // 9 still
const compSqrInc2 = compSqrInc(2); // sqr(3)
compSqrInc2;       // 9 still
```

So functions are composed and interpreted (by the JS interpreter) left to right, while on execution, their values flow through each function from right to left. In short: first outside-in, then inside-out.

But `flip` has the restriction that a flipped composition can't be combined with itself to form a "higher order composition":

```
const comp2 = comp(comp)(comp);
const flipped2 = flipped(flipped)(flipped);
const add = x => y => x + y;

   comp2(sqr)(add)(2)(3); // 25
flipped2(sqr)(add)(2)(3); // "x => f(g(x))3" which is nonsense
```

**Conclusion:** The right-to-left order is traditional/conventional but not intuitive.